# If any request failed how we can execute last request in jmeter

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

I have 6 requests in my jmeter script

Request 1
Request 2
Request 3
Request 4
Request 5
Request 6

If request 3 is failed, directly how we can execute request 6

Please post the ans for this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your Request 6 under a [Test Fragment](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment)
2. Add an [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) after Request 3 and use the following [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) as the condition:

   ```
   ${__jexl3(${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok} == false,)}
   ```
3. Add a [Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller) as a child of the If Controller and point it to the Test Fragment holding the Request 6